# How can I replace duplicate values in the output of a FILTER function in excel with blanks, leaving gaps in the output

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a list of people and their addresses in excel. I have a dropdown that allows me to select a road, which results in my FILTER function returning all of the addresses on that road. Each person has an address associated with their names, so for properties with more than one resident, the output contains duplicates. I would like to replace the duplicates with blanks, so that the address appears next to the name of the first resident, but not the 2nd. Please see below for details:

This formula:

```
=BYROW(FILTER(H:M, N:N=P1),LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,r)))
```

Returns results similar to this:

1 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
1 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
1 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
1 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
3 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
7 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
2 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
2 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
4 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
6 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
8 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
8 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
10 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD

Columns H:M contain the various portions of the address:

H: 1 Fake Road
I: Coolsville
J: Post code

etc.

Column N has a list of road names adjacent to the rest of the address info. P1 is a dropdown populated with unique roadnames from column N.

How can I alter my formula to return only the first instance of each address, while leaving blank lines where the previous duplicates were, e.g.:

1 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
BLANK ROW
BLANK ROW
BLANK ROW
3 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
7 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
2 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
BLANK ROW
4 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
6 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
8 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
BLANK ROW
10 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD

I have tried various suggestions from ChatGPT, including:

```
=LET(output, BYROW(FILTER(H:M, N:N=P1, LAMBDA(r, 
  TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, r))),n,SEQUENCE(ROWS(output)),
  IF(COUNTIF(INDEX(output,,1):INDEX(output,n,1), 
  INDEX(output,n,1))>1, "", INDEX(output,n,1)))
```

Which is a bit beyond my understanding but seems to return a !VALUE error while evaluating the IF(COUNTIF section.

My original formula above is in Column R, so I used this separate formula to create a facsimile of what I want:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($R$2:R2, R2) > 1, "", R2)
```

This is in Column S, and basically returns exactly what I want:

1 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
BLANK ROW
BLANK ROW
BLANK ROW
3 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
7 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
2 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
BLANK ROW
4 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
6 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
8 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD
BLANK ROW
10 Fake Road, Coolsville, AB12 3CD

However I have to copy this formula to as many rows as are filled by the output of the FILTER array, which is manual, and leaves "0" in rows which aren't occupied.

EDIT: Solved by Mayukh Bhattacharya

Your 2nd solution solved it, many thanks! A brilliant solution that solves my problem exactly. As for why I need the spaces, it's probably something I could have worked around, but I'm wrangling some data into a format that will then be exported. I only need each address listed once as a heading, below which will be a list of names of the residents. i.e.

1 Fake Street, Coolsville, AB12 3DC
John Smith
Carol Smith
Linda Smith

2 Fake Street, Coolsville, AB12 3DC
Peter Thomson
Jenny Thomson

3 Fake Street, Coolsville, AB12 3DC
Etc etc

This lets me do that, meaning it's more formatting that I don't need to do elsewhere.

Comment: Why would you want blanks if you can wrap it in UNIQUE() so it will return the uniques only. `=UNIQUE(FILTER(H:M, N:N=P1))` or do you really need them concatenated?

Comment: Just to wrangle the data into a layout that is easier to export. I want to generate a formatted pdf based on chosen road(s) where each address is listed once and a list of residents listed adjacent. I now have a list of the addresses with the correct number of blank rows below. In the next column over I have the list of names, so it's showing as "Column A Row 1 - Address", "Column B Row 1 to 3 - names of residents". Then starting in Column A Row 4 - next address, Column B Row 4 - names of residents etc etc. If that makes sense? Probably a smarter way to do it, but this works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given desired output it seems you are trying to accomplish the following, if so then you could try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     resultfrombyrowfilter, A1#,
     BYROW(resultfrombyrowfilter,LAMBDA(x,
     LET(y,INDEX(resultfrombyrowfilter,1),IF(COUNTIF(y:x,x)>1,"",x)))))
```

---

I tried to reproduce your data example, and came up with this, which you could try as well, if you are trying to return all at once using one formula, although as stated in comments above by @P.b Sir, why would you really need those blanks, if you need uniques only you could have used the `UNIQUE()` function only.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     joiner, BYROW(FILTER(A1:C26,D1:D26=F1), LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ",1,x))),
     IF(SCAN(0,joiner=DROP(VSTACK("",joiner),-1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b,a+1,1)))=1,joiner,""))
```

---

### EDIT:

> *I only need each address listed once as a heading, below which will be*
> *a list of names of the residents. i.e.*
>
> 1 Fake Street, Coolsville, AB12 3DC
>
> John Smith
>
> Carol Smith
>
> Linda Smith
>
> 2 Fake Street, Coolsville, AB12 3DC
>
> Peter Thomson
>
> Jenny Thomson
>
> 3 Fake Street, Coolsville, AB12 3DC
>
> Etc etc
>
> *This lets me do that, meaning it's more formatting that I don't need*
> *to do elsewhere.*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α,C2:C19&", "&D2:D19&", "&E2:E19,
     φ, MAP(UNIQUE(α),LAMBDA(z,z&"/"&TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTER(A2:A19&" "&B2:B19,α=z))&"*")),
     TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("/",,REPT(φ,TAKE(UNIQUE(C2:F19),,-1)=H1)),,{"/","*"}))
```

---

**Mandatory Caveat:** As per **[MSFT Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)**, using `TEXTJOIN()` function on a larger array and If the resulting string exceeds `32767` characters (cell limit), `TEXTJOIN()` returns the `#VALUE!` error. Do take care of this note.

---

Comment: Your 2nd solution solved it, many thanks! A brilliant solution that solves my problem exactly. As for why I need the spaces, it's probably something I could have worked around, but I'm wrangling some data into a format that will then be exported. I only need each address listed once as a heading, below which will be a list of names of the residents.

Comment: Then instead of adding spaces, wrap it in unique: `=UNIQUE(BYROW(FILTER(H:M, N:N=P1),LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,r))))` ?

Comment: If I did this it would be unclear to which address the residents belonged. For example, if I use unique, no spaces are left between addresses, so in Column A it might list 20 unique addresses, filling rows 1-20. In Column B, the list of residents might be 37 people, filling rows 1-37. Obviously it isn't 1 person living at address 1-19 and then the remaining 18 people living at address 20 - I need the spaces so that at a glance I can see where the residents of one address and the next begins, in two columns side by side.

Comment: Then I ask you, what are you really trying to accomplish ax an end goal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got a pretty great answer for the original question already; however, the edit you made to the OP indicates a completely different desired output, with the street addresses displayed as headings, followed by the names of the residents, plus a blank row before the next address. To achieve these results with a single-cell array formula, try something like this:

[image: filter_group.png]

The formula used in cell `I3` in the example shown above is:

```
=LET(arr, FILTER(A2:E19, F2:F19=I1),
n, BYROW(TAKE(arr,, 2), LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN(" ",, r))),
a, BYROW(DROP(arr,, 2), LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN(", ",, r))),
u, UNIQUE(a),
DROP(SORT(VSTACK(HSTACK(u, u), HSTACK(a, n), IFNA(HSTACK(u, ""), ""))),, 1))
```

The basic logic used in this example is to create a "sort field" consisting of the filtered list of addresses, plus the unique list of addresses stacked above and below the filtered results. The stacked array is simply sorted by the sort field, which is then dropped from the final results. Cheers!